# Deserialize Bson file

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization

I have a Bson file generated with the tool mongodump. I want to deserialize within C# code. For that purpose, it seems that I can use mongodb C# driver or the Json.net library.
I tried the both of them but I can't get them to work.

Using the Json.net library :
"input" is the path to the Bson file

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
BsonReader reader = new BsonReader(File.OpenRead(input));
serializer.Deserialize<List<Json.Profil>>(reader);
```

On Deserialize(), I get the following exception :

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MoulinetteConsole.Json.Profil]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

**[EDIT]** If a export the bson to a json file  using the tool bsondump, I get :

```
{ "id" : "1",
  "value" : { "foo" : null, "bar" : "test"}
}
{ "id" : "2",
  "value" : { "foo" : null, "bar" : "test"}
}
```

Moreover, If I replace:

```
serializer.Deserialize<List<Json.Profil>>(reader);
```

by

```
serializer.Deserialize<Json.Profil>(reader);
```

I do not longer get the exception, but I only retrieve the first record of the collection.

Comment: Any success reading a bson file and getting not only the first element? I have the same issue at hand and whatever I do (Newtonsoft, MongoDB, even an online bson => json converter) only gets me the first element.

Comment: It's been a while, but I remember I ended up fixing my problem with a workaround : If you can modify the json file, place the collection under a root element. This way, when deserializing the file, you'll get the root, which is the first element. Then you'll just have to explore its children.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Mjollnir, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I just have the bson file as dump from a MongoDB and want to get the data. Need to find another way around then ...

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the answer. Lets say you are desrializing Animals and you have a class Animal on your c# code that mapps correctly to what you are deserializing. In that case this code will work:

Run this command to make sure you have a bson file:

```
mongodump --db=MyDatabase --collection=Animals --out=/tmp/output
```

Then import the bson generated file as:

```
var path = "/tmp/output/MyDatabase/Animals.bson";

using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
var size = fi.Length;
while (fileStream.Position<size)
{
    var animal = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Animal>(fileStream);
    Console.WriteLine(animal.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file probably contains Json looking like this

```
{
    "foo":1,
    "bar":"baz"
}
```

but by trying to deserialize to `List<>`, the deserializer is expecting

```
[{
    "foo":1,
    "bar":"baz"
},
{
    "foo":2,
    "bar":"baz"
},
...]
```

Simply changing the deserialization line to:

```
serializer.Deserialize<Json.Profil>(reader);
```

should work.

This is what the error is telling you:

> **Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MoulinetteConsole.Json.Profil]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.**
>
> **To fix this error** either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or **change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type** (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, **not a collection type like an array or List**) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: I've omitted to say : the file contains a list of profils. When I use bsondump to see what's in it I have { "foo": 1}{"foo":2}, etc. But there is no root element

Comment: @user3635728 Please post a sample of JSON you are deserializing in your question.

Comment: Ok,I'll do it as soon as possible. Note that with your tip, I successfuly retrieve the first element of the list

Comment: @user3635728 It sounds like your JSON is invalid if it looks like this `{"foo":1}{"bar":2}`. If you have multiple items, it should look like `[{"foo":1},{"bar":2}]`.

Comment: I agree with you, the thing is that I have no control on how the input file is generated. I guess I could programatically add the square brackets...

Comment: You'll need to if you want to deserialize. Don't forget the commas!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property for BSON Reader -- ReadRootValueAsArray = true

Comment: Thx, but I tried this and it only allowed me to read the first element.