# Deserialize mongodb Bson file into List of objects

Tags: c#, mongodb

this answer answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71792264/637142

The problem with that answer is that it is very ineficient. It takes 7 seconds to deserialize 1 million objects on my computer. If I where to get all those million objects directly from the database it will take only 0.5 seconds.

Anyways here is the code I have so far:

Dump all 1 million animals to disk. Takes less than 1 second.

```
// dump all Animals using mongodump command
mongodump --db=MyDb --collection=Animals --out=/tmp/output
```

Read all 1 million animals from c#. Takes less than 1 second

```
var dbName = "MyDb";
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var mongoDb = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Animal>("Animals");
var records = collection.Find("{}").ToList();
```

Read all 1 million animals from bson file /tmp/output/MyDb/Animals.bson file. Takes more than 7 seconds:

```
var path = "/tmp/output/MyDb/Animals.bson";
await using var bsonFileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
var fileSize = new FileInfo(path).Length;


var binaryReader = new BsonBinaryReader(bsonFileStream);
var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<Animal>();
var bsonDeserializationContext = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(binaryReader, null);

var args1 = new BsonDeserializationArgs()
{
    NominalType = serializer.ValueType
};


// keep reading until we reach end of file
while (bsonFileStream.Position<fileSize)
{
    Animal output =  serializer.Deserialize(bsonDeserializationContext, args1);        
}
```

Is there a way I can use the serializer to deserialize a listof animal instead of having to deserialize one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I was so dumb sorry for asking the question.

I was running this code on release mode:

```
var dbName = "MyDb";
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var mongoDb = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Animal>("Animals");
var records = collection.Find("{}").ToList();
```

and because I was not making use of the variable records the time it took to execute the program was very fast. There is no way it will take 1 second to deserialize 1 million objects.

What is impressive is the time it takes to dump all objects using mongodump. But in that case it is just writing the data as it is without having to deserialize the results. That explains why it is so much faster.

Anyways I am not deleting the question in case someone is interested in knowing how to deserialize raw mongodb data into c# objects.